# sideMenuAnimSpeedInt on Toolbar is avaliable?

Tags: codenameone

I'm migrating the MenuBar to Toolbar, the constant sideMenuAnimSpeedInt seams not work.

Is possible to define the openSideMenu speed and close it speed?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new toolbar we migrated to use `InteractionDialog` which has its own hardcoded animation speed. We'll fix that so it takes its speed from the theme too so you should be able to use `interactionDialogSpeedInt` in the same way.

Comment: I think is on this funciton

 p.animateUnlayout(400, 255, new Runnable() 

The duration is 400ms, is posible to changue it anyway?

Regards

Comment: This will be covered by the new theme constant